# Is it possible to use a web hosting plan as a VPS through a PHP shell?

Tags: webserver, vps

I have a web server account on a hosting website and I need a VPS can I turn the server to a VPS?
I think maybe a php file or something like that I can upload and have a vps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on their configuration you may or may not be able to execute commands on the server through a PHP shell. Web hosts generally restrict their servers heavily to prevent users from doing this, and in most cases doing this would violate the provider terms of service for a web hosting plan.

I would say to review their terms of service, and if they do not restrict you from doing so, explore further.